# Looping through rows in a table to get a status update (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have a mailer that I wrote in PHP, and on the front end I have a bit of jQuery that cycles each row and checks whether the email was sent. It is returning correctly as the console is logging the return data, but the elements are not updating to reflect the return.

This is the interval loop inside `$(document).ready(function(){`:

```
setInterval(function(){ updateStatus(); }, 1000);
```

And this is the code I'm using for the function:

```
function updateStatus() {
         var thisEl = $('.recipient-status.processing').first();
         var thisRecipient = thisEl.data('recipient');
         $.get( "<?=$url?>/?try=admin.mailer&action=get_recipient_status&id="+thisRecipient, function(data) { 
          if (data=="complete") { window.location.href='<?=$url?>/admin/mailer?sub=review&id=<?=$this_mailer?>&message=send_mail_complete'; } 
          else { thisEl.attr('class','recipient-status'); thisEl.addClass(data); console.log(data);  } 
         });
      }
```

This is the HTML:

```
<td data-order="<?=$row['status']?>" data-recipient="<?=$row['id']?>" class="recipient-status processing <?=$rs_class?>">
                    <span class="rs-pending">Pending</span>
                    <span class="rs-sending"><div class="loader-dots">Sending<span class="loader__dot">.</span><span class="loader__dot">.</span><span class="loader__dot">.</span></div></span>
                    <span class="rs-sent">Sent</span>
                    <span class="rs-failed-1">Failed - invalid address</span>
                    <span class="rs-failed-2">Failed - mailer error</span>
                  </td>
```

I previously used `each()` but this overloaded when there were over 100 recipients. Today I sent the email to over 1,000 recipients and this is quite common for the site.

In the function above, it is returning the result of each send, but the HTML is not updating. What I need it to do is read the first `.recipient-status.processing`, then reset that cell class to `.recipient-status`, remove all other classes and add the return data as the new class, then proceed to the next `.recipient-status.processing`. This way it shows the status every second for each row. Right now I am not clear on why the console log works on each return but the active row's cell class is not updating.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
$(function(){
  var intv;

  function updateStatus() {
    var thisEl = $('.recipient-status.processing').eq(0).attr("class", "");
    var thisRecipient = thisEl.data('recipient');
    $.get( "<?=$url?>/?try=admin.mailer&action=get_recipient_status&id=" + thisRecipient, function(data) { 
      console.log(data);
      if (data.indexOf("complete") == 0) {
        clearInterval(intv);
        window.location.href='<?=$url?>/admin/mailer?sub=review&id=<?=$this_mailer?>&message=send_mail_complete';
      } else {
        thisEl.addClass("recipient-status " + data);
      } 
    });
  }

  intv = setInterval(updateStatus, 1000);
});
```

Not a lot of suggestions, just a bit cleaner. You may want to consider updating every 5 or 7 seconds instead of every 1 second, just in case your GET request takes longer than expected.